# Publishing target information in Transport package?

Tags: 2011, publishing

We are trying to read transport package to fetch few details about a page on publish.
I could get details like page title version etc. I wanted to get publish target details as well. Where can i get publish target details in a transport package.

Comment: This would be easier in rendering, but what are you trying to do/extend using the transport package itself?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't get Publication Target information in the transport package. The Publication Target is simply the destination(s) to which the package is sent to by the Transport service.

Searching a sample transport package for the string "target", all I find is a possible reference to the Target Type in the instructions.xml file:

```
<Target Type="5" />
```

**UPDATE:**
From the discussion below, it looks like the value in the instructions XML may relate to the target language, not the publication target itself (makes sense). In any case, you should always use the API for information rather than the actual data files in the package (for forward compatibility, etc.), and the API does not appear to have information about the chosen publication target.

Comment: I think that this target "Type" means the target language of the publication target

Comment: @RaúlEscudero Could be - I don't see anything about a language in there. Probably just coincidence that 5 is the number of the Publication Target I used to capture the package. In either case, it's not publicly documented so you can't rely on it

Comment: In the ProcessorInstructions.class, there's a list of target languages: TARGET_LANGUAGE_ASP_JSCRIPT = 1; TARGET_LANGUAGE_ASP_VBSCRIPT = 2; TARGET_LANGUAGE_JSP = 3;
TARGET_LANGUAGE_NONE = 4;
TARGET_LANGUAGE_TCDL = 5;
TARGET_LANGUAGE_REL = 6;

Comment: Thanks @RaúlEscudero, updated the answer to add information about what we have discussed here